# Finding NLTK module in python

Tags: python, module, nltk

I'm trying to use the NLTK module in IDLE but it can't find the module—I noticed NLTK had downloaded to my system's default python directory for the 2.7 version, so I found the file path to the "site-packages" folder in 3.8 and copied NLTK there, but now when I try to "import NLTK" in python I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import nltk
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
    from nltk.internals import config_java
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/internals.py", line 28, in <module>
    from six import string_types
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'
```

Comment: I strongly recommend reading about `venv` or some other virtual environment manager to avoid headaches with this now and in the future.

Comment: 1. Tracebacks look best, with indents preserved, if formatted as if code.  2. Import errors are the same if the code is run within IDLE or with the same python.exe at a command line.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your intention is to use the NLTK package that you have installed for Python 2.7 , in Python 3.8, correct ?
In such case you shouldn't copy the library yourself, but rather use pip3 to install it once again into P3.8.

Comment: Great thanks! Worked like a charm when I did "pip3 install --user -U nltk"

Comment: The reason is that pip3 run on 3.8 got the 3.8 version of nltk, if it is any different from the 2.7 version, *and* installed the 3.8 version of any other modules needed by 3.8 nltk.